# How do I remove the www from my domain URL

Tags: redirection, tomcat7

I am using a tomcat server and I have installed the SSL by changing strings in
server.xml and web.xml file.

Problem is, When I browse with domain.com, www.domain.com, in both the cases it is browsing. But I want it to redirect to domain.com only.

How would I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by Rewrite Valve, it's pretty similar to mod_rewrite in **httpd** :

1- Include rewrite valve in your global context file **context.xml** or your host context **server.xml** , I recommend it here :

```
<Host>
<Context> 
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" /> 
</Context>
</Host>
```

2- Create **rewrite valve** configuration file under the host configuration folder as the above :

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/<host_name>/rewrite.config
```

3- Write your rewrite rule and save the configuration file :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [L]
```

3- Restart **tomcat**

[For a comprehensive review, check the official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: It's not working Mr.Reda Salih. I followed the same method as you mentioned above. But it didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: There is a small typo in the answer: `rewrite.conf` -> `rewrite.config`.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer