# How to rewrite www to non www in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, rewrite

I am running a tomcat server on a vps server which is having centos. My website is browsing with
mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. But I don't want to see www in my url. 
i.e. If I browse with www.mydomain.com, it should be redirected to mydomain.com.

For this thing, I have added Rewrite valve in my context.xml and also created rewrite.config file in
/opt/apache/conf/Catalina/mydomain.com and added below rewrite rules

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

But it is not working. When I browse with www.mydomain.com, the url stays the same. It is not redirecting
to mydomain.com

Please suggest me where I was doing wrong.

Comment: same goes with below ? RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.yourwebsitehere.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://yourwebsitehere.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Not working. Still I can see www in my url after browsing.

Comment: The `RewriteValve` can be configured in two ways: 1. you put the valve in the `<Host>` block and `rewrite.config` in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/<host_name>` or 2. you put the valve in your webapp `context.xml` and `rewrite.config` in the `WEB-INF` folder of you app. @Aravinda Tomcat's `RewriteValve` does not need/support `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Yeah. I followed the second one. But no use.

Comment: In the question you say you mixed up the two ways. Increase the logging level of `org.apache.catalina.valves` to get some feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the www from my domain URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/1002167/how-do-i-remove-the-www-from-my-domain-url)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your rewrite rule has a small error. It should use a full URL for the redirect (cf. [description of **redirect** flag](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html)):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

However this doesn't explain why the rewrite rule is not triggered. As mentioned in the comment above, you must make sure that the `rewrite.config` file is in the write place. With the default `server.xml` configuration (engine name `Catalina`, host name `localhost`) you need to put it in:

- `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost` if you added the `RewriteValve` to the `<Host>` element of your `server.xml`.
- the `WEB-INF` folder of your application, if you added the `RewriteValve` to the `<Context>` element of your application.

In any case it might help you to increase the log level of the Servlet logger:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINE
```

in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties`, which will log to `localhost.<date>.log` the lines:

```
Read configuration from: ...
Add rule with pattern ^(.*)$ and substitution http://example.com$1 
Add condition ^www.example.com test %{HTTP_HOST} to rule with pattern ^(.*)$ and substitution http://example.com$1 [NC]
```

whenever the `RewriteValve` is properly configured.