# how to auto redirect from 8080 port to 8443

Tags: ssl, https, tomcat, redirect

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and apache-tomcat version 6. I changed all necessary things to redirect the port from 8080 to 8443 and it's working fine, but the thing is both urls are working. I would like to auto redirect to 8443(https://localhost:8443) when we open 8080 (http://localhost:8080) and is there any free SSL CA(certificate authority) available to encrypt the data among server and user.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 6.0 is obsolete, so I'll assume you have at least Tomcat 7 (which is available on Ubuntu 14.04). There are basically three ways to force a redirect to `HTTPS`:

- Add a `<security-contraint>` to the `web.xml` files of all your application. If they don't have any, add:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

otherwise add the `<user-data-constraint>` part to the existing `<security-constraint>`.

You can also add the previous snippet to `conf/web.xml`, but that may have **side-effects**: security constraints are selected by the most specific URL pattern. If they have the same URL pattern they are merged: the **less** restrictive contraint applies. E.g. if you use the `/html/*` pattern in `conf/web.xml` it will be merged with **Tomcat Manager**'s contraint and you will be able to log into Tomcat Manager **without** encryption and **without** password.

- You can use a **RewriteValve**: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25873406/11748454) for Tomcat 7 or [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/1002722/530633) for more recent versions.
- Personally I'd recommend to use a reverse proxy like **Nginx** and to perform the redirect on it, rather than Tomcat. There are [lot of questions and answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aserverfault.com+nginx+https+redirect) on this site on how to do it.